# Is it possible to include example mxml in your ASDoc?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, asdoc

Is it possible with ASDoc to include example MXML code in your comment?

```
/**
* @example This should be example code
* <listing version="3.0">
* <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" ...>
* </listing>
*/
```

This produces an empty example code block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but when a browser sees the open and close greater than signs it tries to interpret it as an HTML tag.  So, escape them:

```
/**
* @example This should be example code
* &lt;listing version="3.0"&gt;
* &lt;mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" ...&gt;
* &lt;/listing&gt;
*/
```

Comment: Ah I was trying to wrap in CDATA didn't think to try this, don't know about the includeExample docs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but not if the file you're trying to run asdoc on is an MXML file:

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/ASDoc+in+MXML

copied the whole comment block from ViewStack.as from within the framework as an example of including an mxml file as an example block:

```
/**
 *  A ViewStack navigator container consists of a collection of child
 *  containers stacked on top of each other, where only one child
 *  at a time is visible.
 *  When a different child container is selected, it seems to replace
 *  the old one because it appears in the same location.
 *  However, the old child container still exists; it is just invisible.
 *
 *  <p>A ViewStack container does not provide a user interface
 *  for selecting which child container is currently visible.
 *  Typically, you set its <code>selectedIndex</code> or
 *  <code>selectedChild</code> property in ActionScript in response to
 *  some user action. Alternately, you can associate a LinkBar, TabBar or ToggleButtonBar
 *  container with a ViewStack container to provide a navigation interface.
 *  To do so, specify the ViewStack container as the value of the
 *  <code>dataProvider</code> property of the LinkBar, TabBar or
 *  ToggleButtonBar container.</p>
 *
 *  <p>You might decide to use a more complex navigator container than the
 *  ViewStack container, such as a TabNavigator container or Accordion
 *  container. In addition to having a collection of child containers,
 *  these containers provide their own user interface controls
 *  for navigating between their children.</p>
 *
 *  <p>When you change the currently visible child container, 
 *  you can use the <code>hideEffect</code> property of the container being
 *  hidden and the <code>showEffect</code> property of the newly visible child
 *  container to apply an effect to the child containers.
 *  The ViewStack container waits for the <code>hideEffect</code> of the child
 *  container being hidden  to complete before it reveals the new child
 *  container. 
 *  You can interrupt a currently playing effect if you change the 
 *  <code>selectedIndex</code> property of the ViewStack container 
 *  while an effect is playing.</p>
 *
 *  <p>The ViewStack container has the following default sizing characteristics:</p>
 *     <table class="innertable">
 *        <tr>
 *           <th>Characteristic</th>
 *           <th>Description</th>
 *        </tr>
 *        <tr>
 *           <td>Default size</td>
 *           <td>The width and height of the initial active child.</td>
 *        </tr>
 *        <tr>
 *           <td>Container resizing rules</td>
 *           <td>By default, ViewStack containers are sized only once to fit the size of the 
 *               first child container. They do not resize when you navigate to other child 
 *               containers. To force ViewStack containers to resize when you navigate 
 *               to a different child container, set the resizeToContent property to true.</td>
 *        </tr>
 *        <tr>
 *           <td>Child sizing rules</td>
 *           <td>Children are sized to their default size. If the child is larger than the ViewStack 
 *               container, it is clipped. If the child is smaller than the ViewStack container, 
 *               it is aligned to the upper-left corner of the ViewStack container.</td>
 *        </tr>
 *        <tr>
 *           <td>Default padding</td>
 *           <td>0 pixels for top, bottom, left, and right values.</td>
 *        </tr>
 *     </table>
 *
 *  @mxml
 *
 *  <p>The <code>&lt;mx:ViewStack&gt;</code> tag inherits the
 *  tag attributes of its superclass, with the exception of scrolling-related
 *  attributes, and adds the following tag attributes:</p>
 *
 *  <pre>
 *  &lt;mx:ViewStack
 *    <b>Properties</b>
 *    historyManagementEnabled="false|true"
 *    resizeToContent="false|true"
 *    selectedIndex="0"
 *    
 *    <b>Styles</b>
 *    horizontalGap="8"
 *    paddingBottom="0"
 *    paddingTop="0"
 *    verticalGap="6"
 *    
 *    <b>Events</b>
 *    change="<i>No default</i>"
 *    &gt;
 *      ...
 *      <i>child tags</i>
 *      ...
 *  &lt;/mx:ViewStack&gt;
 *  </pre>
 *
 *  @includeExample examples/ViewStackExample.mxml
 *
 *  @see mx.controls.LinkBar
 *  @see mx.managers.HistoryManager
 *  @see mx.managers.LayoutManager
 */
```

In the documentation about asdoc they mention the comment text should precede any tags and anything following tags should be considered a part of the tag's arguments, only exception being @private.

Also so far as I know and have tried without any success you cannot just put the example inline as your post eludes to.

Comment: I think the includeExample tag is different than what he is asking to do.  I thought that tag related to the "Example" portion that shows up at the bottom of the generated ASDoc.  I think he just wants to show MXML; similar to what is in the 'pre' portion of the sample you copied.  As an aside, is there any documentation on the includeExample tag?

Comment: Yes, I was just showing the @example tag at the bottom of the ASDoc block at the beginning of a class. The solution was to escape the greater than and less than signs, which I should have realized. (doh).

Comment: Cool glad you guys got it figured out I'll try to mentally note this one for future reference too.